# Bootstrap Horizontal Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center-align

[image: post-edit]I'm developing a Spring Boot Web App and am having an issue on the login page, which you can see in the attached picture, where the div is not EXACTLY centered on the page. I'm also using Bootstrap.

It appears that it is nearly centered, but is off a bit to the left for some reason. I've posted my HTML and relevant CSS below. Some parts of it must be conflicting, but I'm not sure where.  [image: login page]

```
<div id="parentLogin">

    <div class="row" style="width: 40%;">
        
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
        
            <div>
                <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                    <div class="login-error" style="margin: 0 auto;">Incorrect username or password</div>
                </c:if>
            </div>
    
            <div class="panel panel-default">
    
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large; margin: 1%;">User Login</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="panel-body">
    
                    <form method="post" action="${loginUrl}" class="login-form">
                    
                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"
                                class="form-control" />
                        </div>
    
    
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                                class="form-control" />
                        </div>
    
                        
                        <button type="submit" class="suit_and_tie">Sign In</button>
                        
                    </form>
    
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

```
#parentLogin {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 75vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div with id="parentLogin" as parent is centered... with a fixed width of 40% of the available width.  But it does not appear that your bootstrap panels inside of that  are centered within that div... you should add classes to the entire chain of child objects... each class should use display: flex; and should specify flex-direction, align-items, and justify-content.  You can use Bootstrap classes for those... but each element in the parent-child chain should specify the alignment of its contents.

```css
#parentLogin {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.parentRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75vh;
}

.parentCol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentLogin">
  <div class="row parentRow" style="width: 40%;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2 parentCol">
      <div>
        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
          <div class="login-error" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            Incorrect username or password
          </div>
        </c:if>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large; margin: 1%;">
            User Login
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form method="post" action="${loginUrl}" class="login-form">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="suit_and_tie">
              Sign In
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked in terms of centering on the page, but shrunk the size of my parent div so that now even though it's centered, the input fields are cut off and User Login goes onto two separate lines. Where should I put a width style in order to keep it centered? If I try to do width: 75% on .panel panel-default, though, it moves it back to the left like was the issue before.

Comment: if the top level is set to width:40 and you want each child div to fill up as much space as possible, make sure to specify flex-grow as at least 1.  So... if a parent has flex-direction as row..  then immediate children with flex-grow: 1 will attempt to grow horizontally as much as possible up to the fixed size of the parent container.  Same for columns.. if parent has flex-direction: column, then immediate children with flex-grow: 1 will attempt to grow vertically as much as possible.

Comment: The question is where to put flex-direction: row and which children to put flex-grow: 1, because for every combination I tried, all that happened was that the div containing all the items on the page moved to the very top of the page, but still centered and not stretched out properly.

Comment: In my response code, I added width: 100% to the parentLogin class.  Did you do the same?  FlexBox works great as long as you master the size of the top level box.

Comment: I've attached above an image of my page currently after adding the CSS ```.parentRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75vh;
}

.parentCol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75vh;
} #profileAbout, #parentLogin {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 75vh;
 width: 100%;
}```